# Secure a Landing Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, security, landing-page, http

I'm trying to have my landing Page HTTPS. 
In this link https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_landing_page.htm&type=5 it's said that there's a check box where you can select the page to be HTTPS, but when creating a new landing, I cannot see this option. Does anyone know where can I find the mentioned checkbox or how can I secure my landing page?
Thanks

Comment: Did you choose a private domain or still using standard domain type for your landing pages?

Comment: I'm selecting a standard domain

Answer (score 2):

You can request an SSL certificate from Salesforce, which will be applied to a.o. your Cloud Pages - when you have applied a Sender Authentication Package, and using your own domain for Cloud Pages. This is a paid feature, which can be requested from your Account Executive. You will need two SSLs to secure all your resources: one for images, another for all other URLs. Please see [this page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232477&type=1) for more details.

If you are using the default domain (https://
pub.STACK.exacttarget.com), and not your SAP domain, you should have an option of selecting HTTPS when creating a new landing page:

[image]

Comment: This is the solution that i'm going to use, but they are taking to long to actívate it, so I need a solution  till i can use SSL